# 3rd term of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

so I  have a function $f(z)=\frac{1-\cos{z}}{\sin{z^2}}$ and I have to compute the first three terms of the power series $f$ at $0$.

So using the taylor expansion of $\sin{z},\cos{z}$ I found out that

$$f(z)=\frac{1-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2+4n}}{(2n+1)!}}$$

wolfram tells me that the expansion at $z=0$ is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{61z^4}{720}$

I don't see how the 2nd and 3rd therm is possible. since if we expand to the 2nd term we get

$$f(z)=\frac{\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^4}{4!}}{z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}}$$

I can see that the first term is correct, but the 2nd term is not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first $z^4$ should be $z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping only needed terms (after dividing out common factors)  $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{2z^4}{6!}}{1-\frac{z^4}{24}}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{2z^4}{6!})(1+\frac{z^4}{24})$.  Expand to get $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z^2}{24}+\frac{61z^4}{720}$